# Extracting a tuple value from a dictionary in python

Tags: python

am working on a restaurant project, and I need a hand :)
so the program will display the main dishes, and the user has to enter which dish he/she wants..
and then the choice will be taken and then added to the bill (dish name, price, num of items)...
so far I chose a dictionary so when the user enters 1  (key), the program will display Mashroum Risto...

this what've created:

```
dishes = {1 : ('Mashroum Risito', 3.950), 2 : ['Tomato Pasta', 2.250],3:['Spagehtie',4.850]}
```

now my question is how to get the dish name without the price (the price is 3.950) and extract it! and also how to get the price without the name so then I can send it into the bill function to calculate it? and if you have any suggestions please go ahead, because i don't know if using dictionary was the right choice

```
def MainDish():

dishes = {1 : ('Mashroum Risito', 3.950), 2 : ['Tomato Pasta', 2.250],3: 
['Spagehtie',4.850]}

dishes.values
print("1. Mashroum Risito       3.950KD")
print("2. Tomato Pasta          2.250KD")
print("3. Spagehtie             4.850KD")
choice = eval(input('Enter your choice: '))
NumOfItem = eval(input('How many dish(es): '))

while(choice != 0):
    print(dishes.get(choice)) #to display the item only without the 
    price
    a = dishes.values()
    recipient(a)
    break
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: `dishes[1][0]` is the name, `dishes[1][1]` is the price. `name, price = dishes[1]` assigns them to neat variables…

Comment: I think for you the dishes are unique objects, I don't know why are you not using them as your keys rather than some numbers.

Comment: Expanding on @HKay, a better structure for the dict would be `{name: price}`, i.e. `dishes = {'Mashroum Risito': 3.950, 'Tomato Pasta': 2.250, ...}` This way it is very easy to iterate over dishes and prices: `for dish, price in dishes.items()`

Comment: Don't use the [dangerous `eval`](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) function when all you need is [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have implemented it:

```
print (dishes[1][0]) #will give you name
print (dishes[1][1]) #will give you price
```

where `[x][y]`

`x` = key in the dict (input in your case)

`y` = element of the value in the dict (0 = name, 1=price in your case)

You should probably create the dictionary better as below:

Follow up question is not so clear but I think this is what you are after roughly. You will need to tweak the returns to your usage:

```
def MainDish():

    NumOfItem = float(input('How many dish(es): '))
    dish = list(dishes)[choice-1]
    cost_of_dish = dishes[dish]
    totalcost = cost_of_dish * NumOfItem
    print (f"\n\tOrdered {NumOfItem}x {dish} at {cost_of_dish}KD each. Total = {totalcost}KD\n")

    return dish, cost_of_dish, totalcost

dishes = {'Mashroum Risito': 3.950, 'Tomato Pasta': 2.250}
for key,val in dishes.items():
    print (f"{list(dishes).index(key)+1}. {key}: {val}KD")


keepgoing = True
while keepgoing:
    choice = int(input('Enter your choice: '))
    if choice == 0:
        keepgoing = False
        break
    else:
        dish, cost_of_dish, totalcost = MainDish()
```

Comment: Yes, i was trying both .. its just a prototype, thank you!

Comment: how can i use this in a loop?

Comment: can you explain why you did this:  dish = list(dishes)[choice-1]
    cost_of_dish = dishes[dish]

Comment: The keys in the dict being used are not integers. 

You would have to reference the key(dish) to get the price of dishname. 

I presume your users do not want to input each dish name and rather the integer corresponding to the dish name. 

To do this we convert the dict into a list and reference the nth element. n = choice-1 since 1st element is 0.

Now we have the selected dish name we get the price by calling the dict value for key=dish name: cost_of_dish = dishes[dish]